# dynamically add a chart to a container

Tags: android, graph, mpandroidchart

I want to create an activity that, depending on what option you chose in the previous activity, will either show a bar chart or line chart. I'm fairly new to android programming and especially new to MPandroidChart, and I'm not yet aware of standard ways of doing things.

Currently i have a program that shows the user a list of options (this is a list of buttons describing the chart to be shown) and when you click on of the buttons it opens a new activity to show this graph. How do i dynamically create the graph and add show it on the screen?

This works if its a Line chart all the time because you can just have a placeholder for a linechart, but what if you want to show different types of graphs in the same activity?

Are you meant to have an empty gridView or LinearLayout that you can add the chart to?

---

Alternatively, this problem all came about because i just wanted a button to close the graph and go back to the list, which i couldn't achieve before as i was just setting the contentView to the chart on button press and I couldn't figure out how to add a back button to the chart. So if its easy to close the chart after opening it in this way, then I wont need this whole extra activity to show the graph with a button and thats problem solved.

---

I would show you the code I have currently, but its just a layout with a button at the bottom that finishes the activity, so it didn't really add value to show you the code.